# Powerpoint 2010: Reapply last text color with keyboard / Default action with ribbon hotkeys

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, colors, hotkeys, ribbon

In Powerpoint 2010 one can click the text-color chooser to reapply the last color selected.

However, when navigating to it with the ribbon hotkeys – in the German version `[Alt], R, F, B` – the color-chooser dialog pops up instead, defaulting to white, which corresponds to the behaviour of the arrow-button next to the text-color button.

[image]

Is it possible with ribbon hotkeys to reproduce the behaviour of the "A" [image] button?